# how to remove the validation css from a specific form-control?

Tags: reactjs, validation, jsx, react-bootstrap

my problem is about a form-control which has no validation conditions but after submit it shows the success mark which i don't need it

so is there a way to remove the validation from it?

```
<Form
   noValidate
   validated={validated}
   onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
>
<Form.Control as="textarea" rows="3" />
```

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the validation entirely, or just the CSS that accompanies the validation?

Comment: anything that will remove the success mark, validation entirely or just CSS, anything would work @Jameslves